# ConvertTextToSmartArt Refuses to work

Tags: vba, runtime-error, powerpoint

Trying to write a simple VBA script to convert a textbox to a smartart object and encountering a few problems.

The line I am using is

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).ConvertTextToSmartArt (Application.SmartArtLayouts(6))
```

But when I try to run this code (Or any other variation I have tried) I get the error code: "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Am I just out of luck when using this for Textboxes?

Do I need to use a different command?

I am just hitting a brick wall with this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Call ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).ConvertTextToSmartArt (Application.SmartArtLayouts(6))
```

or

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).ConvertTextToSmartArt  Application.SmartArtLayouts(6)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I never would have thought to remove the () around the variable. BTW Full name: Justin Bretschneider. Because of course you answered my question.

Comment: Well fancy meeting you here. ;-)   The more general rule is when you're invoking a function, you either use CALL Function (parameters, in, parens) or just Function parameters, sans, parens.  Or Function ParamName1:=Value, ParamName2:=Value and so on.  If the command returns a value or an object, you want to treat it as a function; if it doesn't return anything, you can treat it as a subroutine.